Apache Traffic Server 9.2.x cannot redirect `target` url to `replacement` url that contains a query-string
Recently, I've migrated my environment from the VERY old Apache Traffic Server 5.x to Apache Traffic Server 9.2.x. Everything's working great! EXCEPT I no longer seem to be able to redirect a target url to a replacement url that contains a query string.
Example remap.config configuration (not working as expected):
redirect https://example.com https://google.com?param=value

With the above configuration in place, if a user goes to https://example.com, they'll be redirected to https://google.com (but the query-string parameters are not there).
I've read through the docs and it seems like it's supposed to be able to handle this type of use case, but I can't get it to work. Again, this configuration worked in ATS 5.x.
I've also attempted to use some of the plugins/flags/regex patterns and none of them worked, since they were mostly focused on capturing the query-string on the target url and not the replacement url.
